# Run command twice in a script using shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have this:

`<?php shell_exec('some_command') ?>;`

How can I run 'some_command' more than once?

I'm a code neat freak, calling them more than once kind of an eyesore to me.

Comment: Just do what already works twice. What's the concern?

Comment: Hey what's with the downvote. I'm a code neat freak, calling them twice kind of an eyesore to me.

Comment: What are you expecting, a `for` loop just to do it twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the command twice in the argument:

```
<?php shell_exec('some_command; some_command'); ?>
```

Or call `shell_exec` twice:

```
<?php shell_exec('some_command'); shell_exec('some_command'); ?>
```